# Proving a connected graph with $k$ vertices can be drawn in $k/2$ strokes without repeating edges

Tags: graph-theory

I have been asked to prove that for any given graph $G$ with $k$ vertices, such that $k$ is greater than $0$, the smallest number of strokes (of a pen theoretically) needed to draw the graph without repeating any edge is $k/2$.

I already understand that $k$ must be even due to a derivative of the Handshaking Theorem, but am unsure in how to implement this into my proof or how to prove it altogether.

Comment: What do you mean stroke? Not picking up the pen counts as one stroke?

Answer (score 1):

$k$ need not be even, provided you do not need to spend a stroke
on isolated vertices (in which case the claim is untrue, as demonstrated
by edgeless graphs).

You can use induction on the number $k$ of vertices.
The induction base, $k=1$ or $k=2$ is obvious.

For the induction step, suppose $k>2$.
Now make a maximal stroke. The endpoints of this stroke cannot have any undrawn edges,
or we can prolong the stroke.
So if we remove all edges of this maximal stroke we have a graph with 2 more isolated vertices
and we can apply the induction hypothesis.